# Which types of protectants are safe to use on automotive tires?

Tags: tires, cleaning

Some protectant formulations are known to damage tire rubber and cause sidewall cracking (which can be very dangerous).

What types of tire protectants are recommended to prevent sidewall cracking?  Bonus if it gives the tires a nice shine too! :-)

Comment: Are you looking for some DIY protectant?  There's a big section at most auto parts stores that have nothing but tire dressings.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yes, DIY, but I've learned that just because an item is available at an auto parts store does not make it safe or reliable.